# Using datetime to obtain the time of the next lecture

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Often before the lecture starts, and occasionally in the break I like to display a timer with a countdown until the lectures starts/ resumes while playing some lofi-hip hop in the background. While the university students seems to enjoy this, I am ashamed of the code running the timer.

So my lecture schedules is as follows

```
Monday:    10:15 -- 12:00
Wednesday: 12:15 -- 14:00
Thursday:  08:15 -- 10:00
```

I am interested in finding when my next lecture is in iso format. I did this using the code below and it works fine. E.g if the current time is `16:00` on a Thursday, the output should be Monday and 10:15. I commented out the actual timer, as it is not important.

- ***Is there a better way / cleaner python code to obtain the date and time for my next lecture?***

My attempt (which works, albeit a bit ugly) is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from subprocess import call

# Format (day, hour, minute)
Lectures = [(0, 10, 15), (), (2, 12, 15), (3, 8, 15)]


def get_next_lecture(now=datetime.now()):

    next_lecture = now.replace(minute=15, second=0, microsecond=0)

    # monday = 0, tuesday = 1, ...
    current_day = datetime.today().weekday()
    current_hour = now.hour
    lecture_day = current_day

    correct_day = False
    while not correct_day:
        # If the day is tuesday, increment to wednesday
        if current_day == 1:
            lecture_day = current_day + 1
            lecture_hour = Lectures[lecture_day][1]
            lecture_minute = Lectures[lecture_day][2]
            now += timedelta(days=1)
            correct_day = True
            # if the day is friday, increment to monday
        elif current_day == 4:
            lecture_day = 0
            lecture_hour = Lectures[lecture_day][1]
            lecture_minute = Lectures[lecture_day][2]
            now += datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3)
            correct_day = True
        else:
            # If it is not monday or friday, I have a lecture
            # checks if the lecture is in the future, if else increment day and try again
            if now.hour < Lectures[lecture_day][1]:
                if now.minute < Lectures[lecture_day][2]:
                    lecture_hour = Lectures[lecture_day][1]
                    lecture_minute = Lectures[lecture_day][2]
                    correct_day = True
                else:
                    current_day += 1
                    now += timedelta(days=1)
            else:
                current_day += 1
                now += timedelta(days=1)

    next_lecture = now.replace(
        hour=lecture_hour, minute=lecture_minute, second=0, microsecond=0
    )

    return next_lecture


def launch_timer(time):
    call(["termdown", time.isoformat()])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    next_lecture = get_next_lecture()
    print(lecture)
    # launch_timer(next_lecture)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm seems good, but the `while` loop, and `lecture_hour` and `lecture_minute` variables make your code a lot more complicated.

If we KISS then a simple algorithm is to just remove `()` from `Lectures` and iterate through it, since it is sorted.
The first lecture that is after the current time is the lecture we want.

This is nice and simple:

```py
import datetime


LECTURES = [(0, 10, 15), (2, 12, 15), (3, 8, 15)]


def _get_next_lecture(now):
    today = (now.weekday(), now.hour, now.minute)
    for lecture in LECTURES:
        if today < lecture:
            return lecture


def get_next_lecture(now=None):
    if now is None:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
    day, hour, minute = _get_next_lecture(now)
    return (
        now.replace(hour=hour, minute=minute, second=0, microsecond=0)
        + datetime.timedelta(day - now.weekday())
    )
```

From here we can see if the weekday is 4-6 then `_get_next_lecture` will return nothing and so will error.

This is easy to solve, we just return the first lecture with `+7` days.

```py
def _get_next_lecture(now):
    today = (now.weekday(), now.hour, now.minute)
    for lecture in LECTURES:
        if today < lecture:
            return lecture
    day, hour, minute = LECTURES[0]
    return day + 7, hour, minute
```

With only 3 lectures there's not much point in optimizing further. However if you have more, here is some food for thought:

- You can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to find where to insert into in \$O(\log n)\$ time.
- You can change `LECTURES` into a 7 item list with the weekday as the index and the lectures as the value (always as a list). From here you just find the date using either of the above algorithms.

  This would look like your `Lectures`. But with a list for each day.

  This has either \$O(d)\$ or \$O(\log d)\$ time where \$d\$ is the maximum amount of lectures in a day.

## Test code

```py
def replace(date, changes):
    day, hour, minute = changes
    return date.replace(hour=hour, minute=minute) + datetime.timedelta(days=day)


def test(tests, bases, fn):
    for base in bases:
        date = base.replace(second=0, microsecond=0) - datetime.timedelta(days=base.weekday())
        for test, exp in tests:
            try:
                output = fn(replace(date, test))
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'❌ {test=}, {exp=}')
                print('  ', e)
                continue
            expected = replace(date, exp)
            try:
                assert output == expected
            except AssertionError:
                print(f'❌ {test=}, {exp=}')
                print('  ', date, output, expected)
            else:
                print(f'✔️ {test=}, {exp=}')

TESTS = [
    [(0, 0, 0), (0, 10, 15)],
    [(0, 10, 10), (0, 10, 15)],
    [(0, 10, 15), (2, 12, 15)],
    [(0, 10, 20), (2, 12, 15)],
    [(1, 12, 20), (2, 12, 15)],
    [(1, 13, 20), (2, 12, 15)],
    [(2, 10,  0), (2, 12, 15)],
    [(2, 10,  14), (2, 12, 15)],
    [(2, 12,  15), (3, 8, 15)],
    [(3, 8,  15), (7, 10, 15)],
]
BASES = [
    datetime.datetime.now(),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 1),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1),
    datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1),
]

test(TESTS, BASES, get_next_lecture)
```

Comment: Great answer, gives me plenty to think about!
I was contemplating using the actual weekday names `Monday`, `Tuesday` and then `Thursday`. As it would make it more readable than `0`, `2` and `3`. I can obtain the name of the current day using `now.strftime("%A")`, however it seems harder to iterate over. Thoughts on this?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar You could change the last bullet point to "a dictionary with the weekday name as the key ..." and do that. I'd double check if `%A` is local aware, last thing you want is for it to spit out a non-English name because it's being too nice. (sorry can't remember which ones are) Otherwise it'd be alright, might make iterating a little harder tho if the current day has no lectures.

Comment: @Pelionrayz There is something wrong with your code. You use day, but this returns the day of the month, you need to use `weekday()` =) 

It also seems to fail for the current time? Did you actually test that the code returns the desired output? Seems to be a problem with the and statements

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar No I didn't test it. I fixed those issues now and another :) My test case is small so there may still be some hidden ones :)

Comment: Wont this fail if the month switches? _Scratches head_

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Why do you think months would effect this?

Comment: `datetime.today().replace(day=28+7)` errors in `day is out of range for month`. Which is why I think we need to use `timedelta`? Or rather, that is why I choose to use `timedelta`.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Ok, I've got a pretty full full test suite and it now works fine. I didn't notice you not entering the `day` in replace. It seems like your code fails a significant amount of the time. Can you verify why?